# jQuery clone: cgi generated page

Tags: jquery, cgi

jQuery's clone feature works in a jsfiddle, but not on a CGI generated page.

http://jsfiddle.net/FkrBc/1/

relevant code:

```
var displayDiff = $("#firstTable tbody").clone();

function checkee () {
    $( "tr", displayDiff ).each( function() {
        var foo = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
        $("#firstTable tbody tr td:first-child").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == foo;
        }).parent().attr("class","same");

    });
    var content = $('#firstTable tbody>tr[class!="same"]').clone();
    $("#results").html(content);
}
rowCount = $("tr", displayDiff).length;

setInterval(function(){ 
  if($("#firstTable tr").length > rowCount){
     checkee();
  } 
}, 2000);
```

In the fiddle it only clones once and updates the section with new entries, on the CGI page it looks like it's constantly cloning.

When I test by outputting the clone to a div -- it constantly updates with new rows to the table. Shouldn't do this.

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your update rowCount be inside the checkee() function? Like so:

```
var rowCount = 0; //declare outside of function to maintain scope
function checkee () {
    $( "tr", displayDiff ).each( function() {
        var foo = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
        $("#firstTable tbody tr td:first-child").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == foo;
        }).parent().attr("class","same");

    });
    var content = $('#firstTable tbody>tr[class!="same"]').clone();
    $("#results").html(content);
    rowCount = $("tr", displayDiff).length;  //this line moved to inside this function
}
```

Right now rowCount is only being set once since it's on a standalone line, so the check for

```
$("#firstTable tr").length > rowCount)
```

inside setInterval's function is always true (assuming it's true the first time).

Comment: `rowCount` shouldn't change so I left it outside the function. `rowCount` represents the original number of rows in the table. I want to test for additional rows added.

Comment: Ah I see what  you're saying. Is there a reason you **have** to use setInterval to search for the diffs? Wouldn't it be easier just to make the ClickMe button add to the table and the results div?

Comment: I wish I could --- A submit form is responsible for adding rows. This is a server-side CGI script. My only power on this page is javascript/jQuery.

Comment: are you wrapping all of your javascript within the document.ready event?
`$(document).ready(function(){
//your javascript here
});`

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary with current versions of jQuery. The rest of the script works, but the clone part just keeps cloning. When I count the rows of the 'clone', they increment with the original. Wondering if it would be possible to use html5 localstorage for this.

Comment: Yeah that's probably your best bet :/